# How to convert pdf byte array stored locally to html in android

Tags: android, html, pdf, webview

I have a pdf file in byte array coming from server. I need to display this file inside a webview. The file is downloaded and stored in my sqlite database. If i use third party libraries There are security holes. So i decided to display pdf file by converting it into html and display inside webview. Is there any options to acheive the same

Comment: i have tryied converting byte array to image in android

Comment: I have a pdf file which is stored in Db as byte array. Now i need to display this within my app. I have a header and footer in my app pdf should be displayed within it